# Draw star using tkinter

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, background-image, project

I'm trying to set a background image on my Tkinter canvas and draw a star above it.
Here's my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk

# Create a new Tkinter window
root = tk.Tk()

# Load the background image
background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\Stefa\\Downloads\\galaxy.jpeg")

# Create a new canvas
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=background_image.width(), height=background_image.height())
canvas.pack()

# Add the background image to the canvas
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw', image=background_image)

# Define the coordinates for the vertices of the star
points=[200,20,80,396,380,156,20,156,320,396]

# Draw a polygon connecting the vertices to create the star
star_image = tk.PhotoImage(width=200, height=200)
star_canvas = tk.Canvas(star_image, width=200, height=200)
star_canvas.create_polygon(points, outline='blue', fill='blue')
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw', image=star_image)

# Start the Tkinter event loop
root.mainloop()
```

When I execute this code, my program states:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Stefa\Videos\Python exam\stef.py", line 7, in <module>
    background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\Stefa\\Downloads\\galaxy.jpeg")
  File "C:\Users\Stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4093, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Stefa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4038, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "C:\Users\Stefa\Downloads\galaxy.jpeg"
PS C:\Users\Stefa\Videos\Python exam>
```

Comment: Tkinter does not support Jpeg images on its own. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#images)

Comment: The Tkinter does support jpeg. I had tested jpeg.

Comment: i found a solution yes it does support jpeg

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Forgotten to draw a star.

- In line 10 add constant 200.
- Comment out line line 20, 21 and 23

The Tkinter does support jpeg.

Add `r` in front of path.

```
background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"C:\\Users\\Stefa\\Downloads\\galaxy.jpeg")
```

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk

# Create a new Tkinter window
root = tk.Tk()

# Load the background image
background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=r"C:\\Users\\Stefa\\Downloads\\galaxy.jpeg")

# Create a new canvas
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=background_image.width()+200, height=background_image.height()+200)
canvas.pack()

# Add the background image to the canvas
canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw', image=background_image)
 
# Define the coordinates for the vertices of the star
points=[200,20,80,396,380,156,20,156,320,396]

# Draw a polygon connecting the vertices to create the star
#star_image = tk.PhotoImage(width=200, height=200)
#star_canvas = tk.Canvas(star_image, width=200, height=200) 
canvas.create_polygon(points, outline='blue', fill='blue')
#canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw', image=star_image)

# Start the Tkinter event loop
root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]